# How to work with coding styles clashe within a single project across different languages?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, coding-style

In Python underscores are used for variables:

```
some_long_var, my_name, first_name, etc.
```

In JavaScript camelcase is preferred:

```
someLongVar, myName, firstName, etc.
```

All is fine and dandy until the two technologies start interacting:

JS Ajax Call:

```
$.get('url', {foo_bar: fooBar, bar_baz: barBaz}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data.computed_result);
};
```

Python view:

```
def url():
    foo_bar = request.GET.get('foo_bar')
    bar_baz = request.GET.get('bar_baz')
    return jsonify(computed_result=foo_bar + bar_baz)
```

Do I use the Python or the JS style within the data JSON object sent to the server?

What about the JSON response?

Comment: Do you work in a team?

Comment: It varies from project to project. This is a recurring issue.

Comment: What about coding do you write once and forgive or do you read a lot later? Do you maintain code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick one and be consistent. I write Python a lot, therefore I would choose the Python style, which is concerned with readability for non-native-English speakers. However, reasonable people could disagree. Build concensus on your team, and take what you can best agree to be the best course of action.